# Parsing params from url to next page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parsing, url, hidden

I currently have a landing page `/vouchers` and then many pages linked to that for example `/vouchers/1`, `/vouchers/2` etc.

I currently have the functionality that if this is entered `/vouchers/1?offer=50` then the form on that page is sent with the offer included in the url.

Now I need to add the functionality so if `/vouchers?offer=50` is entered, any page that is then navigated to, will keep these parameters. (for example `/vouchers/1` should then include the offer from the url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, probably not in the best way. On the `/voucher` page, I added if statements to all the links, so if there's an offer in the url, the links are appended appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I see only one way.

- store all "special" parameters in session
- in any handler — if "special" parameters are in session — form new url with this parameters and redirect user there

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess :
1. you have a model , named "Voucher"
2. In case you want to see the entry for , let's say , voucher#1 , you see URL voucher/1 (notice the singular form of the word 'voucher') 
3. you assign the value of the offer by some interaction by user , for example - link or list . Let's say it's a link . Try this (HAML):

```
= link_to "Accept this offer and create a new voucher", new_voucher_path(:offer => @offer_value)
```

(in your case @offer_value = 50)

The following view (or partial ) will be able to read the value in :offer .

You can refer to [this useful discusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207038/the-better-way-to-pass-the-foreign-key-value-to-the-rails-controller) .