# How to use nested attributes with belongs_to association on new action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

On the `update` action the following `nested_form` works, but on `create` I get this error:

```
Couldn't find Student with ID=12 for Cv with ID=
```

*Controller:*

```
def new
  @cv = Cv.new
  @cv.student = current_student
end

def create
  @cv = Cv.new(params[:cv])

  if @cv.save
    redirect_to student_dashboard_path,
      notice: t('activerecord.successful.messages.created', model: @cv.class.model_name.human)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

*Model:*

```
class Cv < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :student_attributes

  belongs_to :student
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student
end
```

*View:*

```
= f.simple_fields_for :student do |s|
  = s.input :english_level, collection: [['Low', 1], ['High', 2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make changes to your route.rb too.

```
resources :parent do
  resources :child
end
```

Take a look at this useful implementation by Jose Valim - [inherited-resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) .

Comment: I can see in your controller , there are missing parts , building associates between resources . You can reference here in [this discusion]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207038/the-better-way-to-pass-the-foreign-key-value-to-the-rails-controller .