# Rails devise: user_signed_in? and current_account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sessionid

I'm using devise for authentication in my Rails application. Currently I have two models:

```
Users
Accounts
```

Accounts belong to Users and users have one Account.

My account model includes has a name and a subdomain. My user model has email and password

In account.rb I have:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :subdomain

  belongs_to :user

end
```

And in user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :Trackable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :account_attributes, :account
  has_one :account
end
```

I need to get the name and sudbomain etc. from Account after a user signs in.

In my application_controller.rb I have:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.is_a?(User)
    user_path  
  else
    super
  end
 end

  def current_account
    @iduser = session[:user_id]
    @current_account ||= Account.find(@iduser) if @iduser
  end
  helper_method :current_account
```

And in layout.html.erb

```
<% if current_account %>
  <%= current_account.name %> <%= current_account.subdomain %>
<% end %>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  |
  <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, :class => "btn btn-mini btn-danger", :method => :delete do %>
  <i class="icon-off icon-white"></i> logout
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, name and subdomain don't show. How can I get them to display?

Comment: Try and be tidier with your questions so they're easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this in your view:

```
 <%= current_user.account.name %>
 <%= current_user.account.subdomain %>
```

And have you correctly included the user_id in the account model?

Not sure you really need to worry about that helper particularly. Get the basics working first before you delve into helper methods.

Comment: Glad to hear it, good luck. I fall foul of this stuff all the time still. Remember that Rails wants it to be simple. Try and not over complicate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if User have one account , it should be mentioned in the model , like (in User model):

```
has_one :account
```

and in Accounts model :

```
belongs_to :user
```

This creates a column in the database accounts , named user_id (but if you are editing the existing model , you should add it by migration and then rake db:migrate) . Then in the helper  , where you extract the name and subdomain you can call :

```
@current_account = current_user.account
```

Be careful if you are assigning user_id trough user interface , you should include in your Account model :

```
attr_accessible :user_id
```

EDIT : In fact , creating records for models , containing has_one and belongs_to , requires association . More about creating records trough association you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431465/how-to-use-nested-attributes-with-belongs-to-association-on-new-action/13431671#13431671) . You may consider reading about [nested resources in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) , it is very useful article . Here is another [interesting discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207038/the-better-way-to-pass-the-foreign-key-value-to-the-rails-controller) on topic .