# Ruby on rails 2 level model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need some help creating a very simple forum in a existing model.

What I want in a Game page, have a mini forum, where is possible create some topics and some comments to this topics. In the beginning I'm only implement topics.

This is the error I have:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'user_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `topics` (`game_id`, `question`, `user_id`) VALUES (1, 'asd', NULL)
```

This is my main model:

**game.rb**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name

   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

   belongs_to :user

   has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy

end
```

**topic.rb**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates_presence_of :question
     validates_presence_of :game_id

     attr_accessible :question, :user_id

     validates :question, length: {maximum: 50}, allow_blank: false

     belongs_to :game
     belongs_to :user
end
```

**topic_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    @topic = @game.topics.create(params[:topic])
    @topic.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Topic was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
end
```

**game/show.html.erb**

```
<h2>Topics</h2>
<% @game.topics.each do |topic| %>

    <p>
      <b>Question:</b>
      <%= topic.question %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a topic:</h2>
<%= form_for([@game, @game.topics.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :question %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :question %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: since your problem is easily solvable by debugging - just use [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) for finding your problem in such simple cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue you're experiencing is the difference between `create` and `new` in Rails.

Using `new` merely initializes the model, allowing you to save/validate later; using `create` will perform all of those steps in one command, causing the database row to be created.

So when you attempt to perform

```
@game.topics.create(params[:topic])
```

Rails attempts to create a Topic using `params[:topic]` and setting the `game_id` to `@game.id`, after which it immediately attempts to validate this new Topic that it created and save it to the database.

Potential options that you can consider:

1) Use `@game.topics.new(params[:topic])`

2) merge `{:user_id => current_user.id}` in: `@game.topics.create(params[:topic].merge({:user_id => current_user.id})`

I'd personally suggest option 1 (i.e. using new instead), but I have seen option 2 used before.

**EDIT:** Another issue that it looks as though you might be experiencing: should `current_user` be `@current_user` in your code?

---

Side note: 
generally, if `create` fails to create database row, it will still work (returning the initialized model instead), but in your case it looks like this won't happen due to database-level restrictions on user_id being NOT NULL, causing an uncaught error.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider reading the [Rails Guide on nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). I've been where you are now , take a look at [this discusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207038/the-better-way-to-pass-the-foreign-key-value-to-the-rails-controller).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're accessing the site without being logged in, so `user_id` will not be set. You should ensure that there is a logged in user for all actions that are modifying or creating a topic. A simple approach can be found in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/20-restricting-access).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! 
In the beginning I think that's the problem but no, i'm logged.

Answer (score 0):

I think `current_user.id` is not setting properly,  Do inspect these issue are almost all the other issues, ruby debugger is the beset way

in your GEM file add

*GEM file*

```
gem 'debugger'
```

run `bundle install`

then in your controller

```
def create
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    @topic = @game.topics.create(params[:topic])

    @topic.user_id = current_user.id

    debugger

    respond_to do |format|
      if @topic.save
        format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Topic was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
end
```

and this will stop you in the the debugger line, then from the console you could see if the values are set or not. [check this for more](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger)

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but I already solve the problem with @DRobinson answer ;)