# Passing attributes into a belongs_to Rails object in between "new" and "create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, view

This is a question which I am sure is easily solved and attributed in part to my own lack of knowledge, but I've done a bit of searching and can't figure out the proper solution to my problem.

In my situation, I have a class *Product* which has many *Review* objects. The reviews also belong to *Users*. Assuming I have defined my models correctly, I am having difficulty in figuring out how to correctly pass a *:product_id* variable into the review in order to tie a given review to a given product upon submission.

What I have thus far is a view displaying product information as well as a *link_to* in the form of `<%= link_to 'Review Product', new_review_path(:product_id => @product.id) %>`. The resulting view form for adding a new review (intended to be for that product) appears at least somewhat correct, as the URL displays as *http://localhost:3000/reviews/new?product_id=1*. I have done prior searching, as I mentioned, and similar answers to my sort of question have been provided, but it has not resolved the issue, as when I display the values of the `@review` instance variable, each property is nil.

In my *reviews_controller.rb* file, I can assign these variables -- at least within the *new* action's form, by doing something similar to the following:

`@review = Review.new(:product_id => params[:product_id])`

I can also assign the *user_id* variable by doing something similar and passing the *current_user* variable (handled by the devise gem). I am aware that the *create* action which Rails employs typically creates a new instance of the variable, based on everything I have read. However, doing that causes a loss of data with the exception of the variables I have input in the form. Technically speaking, I should be able to pass the *current_user* variable in the *create* action, but I cannot pass over (or do not know how to pass over) the product variable. For what it's worth, I'm not using nested routes of any sort right now, but I don't know if that is a direct solution.

If anyone has a better understanding of what I might be able to do to solve this problem, I would appreciate the help. I'm sure that, as I hinted at, it's an amateur mistake.

P.S. I apologize if the question wording is awkward, as I'm not sure of the best way to describe it.

Comment: You can take a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) about nested attributes . It seems to me that you should use nested routes .

Comment: I'll look at it. I was actually doing so before but perhaps I didn't implement it in a way that would solve my issue.

Comment: I've been in your situation - [here is my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207038/the-better-way-to-pass-the-foreign-key-value-to-the-rails-controller)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use nested routes like Qumara suggests (and I would agree) then you need to set add the following to app/views/reviews/new.html.erb so that it is available to your create action.

```
<%= r.hidden_field :product_id %>
```

Keep in mind of course that this means I could hack your form and set my review to whatever product I wanted if I knew the product id.  So you might want to think about that...

Answer (score 0):

**Nested resource routes** is probably the best way to go.
@PhilipHallstrom's way works in `form` elements, but if your looking for the **Restful** approach:

```
# Add nested resource route 
# /config/routes.rb
resources :products do
    resources :reviews
end


# In your 'products/show.erb.html'; @product will be the instance you want to review
<%= link_to 'Review Product', new_product_review_path(@product) %> # gets you to ReviewController#new

# In your ReviewsController#new
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@review = @product.reviews.new #this should have product_id


# In your 'reviews/new.erb.html'
<% form_for [ @product, @review ] %> # gets you to ReviewController#create


# In your ReviewsController#create
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@review = @product.reviews.new(params[:review]) # params from the previous form
@review.user = current_user
@review.save
```

As far as passing `current_user` or `@product` through the form params that wont work.  You can't technically pass an actual Ruby Object through HTTP.

`current_user` will still be there in the controller so there's no point, and its bad for security.

`@product` you will need to query the DB from the controller, using the `product_id`