# Where can I find a beginners Ruby On Rails tutorial that covers two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-for-zombies

I've made a ton of progress in Ruby On Rails. I'm trying to grasp my head around making something with two models/tables. **Do you know of any basic tutorials that have two models?**

For example I did the Rails for Zombies course and it skims over `tweet belongs_to zombie` and `zombie has_many tweets` but it doesn't really discuss how to setup that second model or make use of it.

In the little application I'm working on I've now made a model **company** and model **employee** and added the `company has_many employees` and `employee has_one company` but not sure where to go next and could really use a tutorial that covers this. For example I made company like so:

`rails g scaffold company name phone website city state twitter`

to now make the employee model I did: `rails g scaffold employee name phone email`

Will the act of associating them automatically add the additional column needed so that `employee` has a company_id or should I have created that? And how would I update the employee form so that I can select which company it belongs to?

Comment: I have been there ,it is possible [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207038/the-better-way-to-pass-the-foreign-key-value-to-the-rails-controller) to be your guide.

Comment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ is $26 but well worth the money, he does a great job. Not affiliated in any way, just a happy customer.

Comment: I stand corrected, he now offers the book itself for free online: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: @MattGreer I bought that book a long time ago and got incredibly frustrated trying to setup Heroku, Git and Rspec in the first few chapters. My friend told me not to use that tutorial until I can learn  more and its been going much smoother ever since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick tutorial:

Let's create a company

```
rails g scaffold company name
```

Let's create an employee, and tell Rails that employee will reference the company (will belong to it)

```
rails g scaffold employee company:references name phone email
```

Note that in the above command, it is the `company:references` that creates the column "company_id" for the employee.

Update your database

```
rake db:migrate
```

Let's update the employee form. Change

```
<%= f.text_field :company %>
```

to a select box that gets its options from a collection, in this case all Companies

```
<%= f.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true %>
```

And, to see the company name, let's edit app/views/employees/show.html.erb

```
<%= @employee.company.name %>
```

Finally, edit your app/models/company.rb and add this line

```
has_many :employees, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Didn't expect someone to just write it up but certainly appreciate it!